# Could not import setting.views.types. View does not exist in module setting.views

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

widgets.py

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.forms.widgets import Widget, Select
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings


class CheckboxDivSelectMultiple(CheckboxSelectMultiple):
'''renders the checkboxes as divs with a hard coded class'''

def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, choices=()):
    if value is None: value = []
    has_id = attrs and 'id' in attrs
    final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, name=name)
    output = [u'<div>']
    """""""""
        option_label = conditional_escape(force_unicode(option_label))
        output.append(u'<div class="%s"><label%s>%s %s</label></div>' % ('new-class', label_for, rendered_cb, option_label))
    output.append(u'</div>')
    return mark_safe(u'\n'.join(output))
```

forms.py

```
class TypeSelectionForm(forms.Form):
    checkbox_field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxDivSelectMultiple(), label="", required=False)
```

I am overriding the checkboxselectmultiple with custom widget.I placed the widget code in widgets.py.it is returned with error "ViewDoesNotExist at /setting/type/"

Below traceback:

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.100.12/setting/type/

Django Version: 1.4.1
Python Version: 2.7.0

Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  300.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  300.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  209.             return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  216.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  27.         result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  101.                     (lookup_view, mod_name))

Exception Type: ViewDoesNotExist at /setting/type/
Exception Value: Could not import setting.views.types. View does not exist in module setting.views.
```

Comment: Could you post your urls.py?

Comment: @zero323 i updated the urls.py in question.

Comment: Is this your global url for the project? or url for a particular app?

Comment: @matcheek this is url for this particular app.

Comment: So, do you actually have a `types` function in `setting.views`? Might have been nice to post it if so.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your imports, shouldn't this line:

```
class CheckboxDivSelectMultiple(CheckboxSelectMultiple):
```

be this?

```
class CheckboxDivSelectMultiple(forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple):
```